# Is there any situation where it's appropriate to flag a comment on a deleted post as "No longer needed"?

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags, deleted-posts

I know that deleted posts are hidden from the majority of the viewers, and same goes for the comments that were on the posts before they got deleted. There is still the option to flag such comments, and rightfully so.

However, the *"No longer needed"* option will still be available. **Is this necessary?** Because I'm assuming that flagging those *(just the "No longer needed" ones, to be clear)* would just bring in a lot of unnecessary work for the moderators.

I did flag a comment (on a deleted post) that only said:

> :)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

as *"No longer needed"*, which, as I now understand why, got declined.

Comment: Only one I can come up with is when you're cleaning up a post towards getting it undeleted, by e.g. editing. In that case it makes no sense to have to wait with flagging no longer needed comments pointing out improvements that are now made until after said post is undeleted.

Comment: That emote of ))) seems good tho